# What will be the context for CustomAdapter class

Tags: android, listview

I want to use CustomAdapter but context problem ahead. I doesn't understand what will be the context for this. I used **Blocklist.this** context but it doesn't work. 
kindly help me.

Blocklist.java

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blocklist);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        adapter = new CustomAdapter(**Blocklist.this**, R.layout.custom_textview, arrayList); 
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.blockList); 
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

CustomAdapter.java

I think the problem in **public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter** line because i use **HashMap** in Blocklist.java class. If this then kindly tell me code should be use or what not?

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> list;

    public CustomAdapter (Context context, int resourceId, List<String> list) {
        super(context, resourceId, list);
        mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
        mContext = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.list = list;
    }
```

Comment: is Bloclist an Activity ?

Comment: yes, Blocklist is an activity

Comment: the problem is not Context. The third parameter of your `CustomAdapter`  is `List<String> list`  and you are passing  `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>`

Comment: could you edit my code to correct it?

Comment: why don't you try yourself ?

Comment: public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, Object>> {

    private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context mContext;
    private List<HashMap<String, Object>> list;

    public CustomAdapter (Context context, int resourceId, List<HashMap<String, Object>> list) {
        super(context, resourceId, list);
        mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
        mContext = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.list = list;
    }

Comment: holder.itemName.setText(list.get(position));